# Windows CE, .NET - how to get CPU ticks or current time in (micro) milliseconds?

Tags: .net, windows-ce, milliseconds

I would like to test how difficult are lines of code I wrote. I need to know how long (or how many CPU ticks) it takes to complete them.

I use Windows CE, compact .NET framework 2, VB.NET 2005

On Google and here I found only solutions that work on desktop Windows, not mobile. I tried following:

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
'and
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "coredll.lib" () As Long
Dim lngStart As Long = GetTickCount() 'did not work

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ' does not exist

System.DateTime.Now() ' resolution only seconds I need at least milliseconds

System.Environment.TickCount ' same as Now()

(DateTime.Now-new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds ' only seconds
```

... and much more. **Nothing worked**.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `GetTickCount` API returns a DWORD, which is a 32-bit integer.  That corresponds to a managed `Integer` *not* a `Long` so that's explains the P/Invoke failure.
2. `DateTime.Now` just calls the `GetSystemTime` API which, in every CE device I've used since back in the 2.0 days, did not have millisecond resolution.  Now the OEM of any device *could* give it ms resolution, but I've never seen it (well I saw it once in an OS that I built for a customer who specifically wanted it). A resonable workaround [can be found here](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/11/20/getting-a-millisecond-resolution-datetime-under-windows-ce.aspx).
3. `Environment.TickCount` calls the `GetTickCount` API, which typically returns milliseconds since the processor started, with a wrap at something like 22 days.  It is *not* processor ticks.  It is much slower.
4. Some devices support a higher-resolution counter, which can be queried by P/Invoking `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get (obviously) the frequency and current value.  This often has a hns (hundreds of nanoseconds) resolution.  Though if you're concerned about things at this level, I might begin to question your choice of managed code.  At any rate, an example for this [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446542.aspx).
5. If you're looking at code performance and the CF then [this article](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2008/01/31/performance-implications-of-crossing-the-p-invoke-boundary.aspx), while a bit old, is still valid and informative.

***EDIT***

Since you mentioned the `Stopwatch` class in your question:

1. There's an implementation of the Stopwatch class that works with CF 1.0 and CF 2.0 in the old 1.x SDF source code.  You can [download the full (free) 1.4 source here](http://www.opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=65) (bottom middle of the page).